# error: type mismatch: inferred type is String? but Boolean was expected

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to pass a parameter that's a type String? to a function that needs a Boolean type but I'm not sure how to make it work since if the String? is empty, it should be false, otherwise true.

This is the code:

```
data class House(
    var article: Article,
    var totalTime: Calendar){

    val totalTime: Long
        get() = (Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis - totalTime.timeInMillis) / MIN_IN_MILISEC

    fun takeArticleOut(artCode:String){

        fun onSuccess(finalPrice:Int):String{
            val finalPrice = getTime(vehicleType = article.articleType,
                totalTime = article.totalTime.toInt(), hasCard = article.articleCard)

            return "Price is $finalPrice."
        }
    }

    fun getTime(articleType: ArticleType, totalTime:Int, articleCard:Boolean): Int {
        var finalPrice = 20
        if (totalTime > 30) {
            finalPrice += ((totalTime - 30) / 15) * 10
        }
        return finalPrice
    }

    if(hasDiscountCard){
                val discount = (finalPrice * 15) / 100
                finalPrice = finalPrice - discount
                return finalPrice
            }

            return finalPrice

        }

data class Article(val artCode: String,
                   var articleType: ArticleType,
                   var totalTime: Calendar,
                   var articleCard:String?=" "){

    val totalTime: Long
        get() = (Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis - checkInTime.timeInMillis) / 60000 //minutes in milliseconds
}
```

The error comes from this part, with the hasCard because article.articleCard is a String? and I need a boolean. How can I pass the parameter in a way that it works?

```
fun onSuccess(finalPrice:Int):String{
            val finalPrice = getTime(articleType = article.articleType,
                totalTime = article.totalTime.toInt(), hasCard = article.articleCard)

            return "Price is $finalPrice."
        }
```

Comment: *"How can I pass the parameter in a way that it works?"* - it depends how you want it to work? The `hasCard` parameter should be true if you have a card, false if not, but how you determine this depends on your logic. Maybe `articleCard` being null means you don't have a card? If so you would pass `[.].articleCard != null`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert `String?` to `Boolean`. If what you need is:

- null -> false
- "" -> false
- non-empty string value -> true

Then the easiest is to use `isNullOrEmpty()`:

```
hasCard = !article.articleCard.isNullOrEmpty()
```